# Send firebase firestore data string in to flutter text string

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, marquee

I want to have an scrolling information textfield on my startpage... i found an dependency called marquee. It's working really really good but my problem is that i can't leave this text hardcoded so i want to change it via firebase firestore. My question is if i can somehow read the data from the database and push it into an string that i can insert to marquee. I've already tried it a couple times with ListViews (Flutter Fire Documentations) but when i'm inserting this my ide tells me that only a string is possible. (marquee only accepts text strings)

Thanks in advance! (If you need some kind of code please ask!)

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Can you add some code so that we can know what you are doing.